# is it possible to skip the PDF preview screen while printing using window.print() in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an iframe that has a PDF loaded.

```
   <iframe src='some pdf url' id='print-pdf' style="border:0;display: none;"></iframe>
```

and using the below code to print the PDF.

```
  let print_iframe = document.getElementById("print-pdf").contentWindow;
  print_iframe.focus();
  print_iframe.print();
```

And it's showing pdf Preview with a print option or save as PDF which normally comes using CMD + P.

So I want to skip that PDF preview screen and print the PDF directly.

Comment: How would the user determine which printer to print to?

Comment: assuming that a default printer is already connected.

Comment: Seems like a *huge* assumption.  Does the user want to send to their black and white laser printer to save money?  Their photo printer? Their colour printer?  In an office, do they want to send to the printer next to their hotdesk, or the one they last used in a different office?   What if they want multiple copies (which the print-dialog provides an option for)?  Or only a specific page?  There's a reason this dialog is shown and no good reason not to show it (IMO).

Comment: I know there are lot of possibility. but it will be used for specific controlled environment. https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-HTML-from-Javascript-to-client-printer-without-print-dialog-silently/ this article tells how we can silent print but i wanted some javascript solution.

Comment: bro leave it I already found the solution. instead of giving some solution, you guys are just making it a social platform. leave it. The browser doesn't all by default to skip that preview but if you use browser-specific mode like chrome's kiosk mode the preview can be skipped. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i was able to find a alternate for this.
By default chrome or some other browser doesn't allow default preview skip.
Using kiosk mode we can skip the print preview.
e.g.
`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --kiosk --kiosk-printing`